# How to fix Django Custom Filter: "namespace is not bound error"

Tags: django, pycharm, django-2.1

I've created a simple custom filter to check if an "< option >" in a "< select >" is selected. It is working fine tho, it's just that it has an error on the pycharm editor "namespace is not bound" and the filter is highlighted red. clearly there's something wrong.

this is my custom filter

cus_filter.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_option_selected(value, to_compare):
    return "selected" if value == to_compare else ""
```

my application:

```
{% load cus_filters %}

<label>LONG/SHORT</label>
<select class="form-control">
    // {{ data.type|is_option_selected:"Short/Long"}} is highlighted red with error: "tooltip Namespace 'data.type|is_option_selected' is not bound. "
    <option {{ data.type|is_option_selected:"Short" }}>Short</option>
    <option {{ data.type|is_option_selected:"Long" }}>Long</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is `data.type` here?

Comment: {{data.type}} returns a string either "Long" or "Short" sir.

Comment: Ah, but you retur a `true` or `false`, so you should wrap in in an `{% if ... %}`.

Comment: I am returning a  string "selected" or a blank ""

Comment: Does PyCharm provide any suggestions? Usually doing what it suggests is enough.

Comment: it suggested "create a namespace declaration".  I am usually doubtful of these suggestions, sometimes it destroys the code, and crtl+z wont save it. hehe